# \b vs \\b in regex

Tags: objective-c, regex, word-boundary

As I see in regex documentation that \b match word boundary.
I prepare a string

> "db bd how to"

and regex

> \b(a|b)(c|d)\b

I think when running the regex, it should match "bd" in the string, but it don't.

But if the regex is

> \\b(a|b)(c|d)\\b

it matches.

Can you explain the difference?

Comment: Which language are you using, Objective-C?

Comment: That really depends on the context. If you provide the expression in a string, in most programming languages the ``\`` is the escape character in strings as well, so you have to escape it ``\\`` to create a literal backslash for the expression. Otherwise, depending on the language, the expression might end up as `b(a|b)(c|d)b`.

Comment: @KennyTM: Yes, I use Objective-C

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several layers of escaping at work here

```
regex -----------------> | regex literal -> | string literal
-------------------------+------------------+---------------
word boundary            | \b               | \\b
alternation ("a" or "b") | (a|b)            | (a|b)
alternation ("c" or "d") | (c|d)            | (c|d)
word boundary            | \b               | \\b
```

Answer (score 1):

If that is in a C or C++ program, the compiler itself might interpret the '\b' and substitute it during compilation, so you need to escape it from the compiler first.

So if you have

```
char *regex = "\\bword";
```

in your source file, and pass it to a regex function, it will receive '\bword'.

---

**Edit**

I have no idea if it holds for Objective-C, I have no experience with it.

Comment: Thank you, your answer is correct. But I choose Tomalak for more explaination